# Advantages and disadvantages of including JS/CSS inside the HTML?

Tags: javascript, performance, html, http, css

What are the advantages and disadvantages of including JS/CSS inside the HTML instead of separated files?

Specifically concerned about performance issues, for example, if the CSS and JS are small and simple, and they are not going to be used in any other page, is it better to include them with the HTML so there is only a single request to the server? Or is this not a concern anymore with HTTP/2?

Which other technical considerations are important regarding this decision?

Comment: It is a matter of taste, and the HTML and JavaScript and CSS contents may be generated (like [Ocsigen](https://ocsigen.org/) does, and [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) could do...). Contact me by email to `basile@starynkevitch.net`. See also [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for the heads up! I updated the question to focus it on a more fact-based line.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I followed the links you suggested me to follow but I cannot find any relation with the question asked or how they add to the discussion... could you please expand on why you posted and suggested to follow those links? Seems like they are projects made by you. Is that spam? Sorry if I'm getting it wrong, appreciate if you clarify.

Comment: No, [ocsigen](http://ocsisgen.org/) is not by me, and I never used it. I happen to know (in person) its contributors. Please email me for more (to `basile@starynkevitch.net`). Being on summer holidays (in august 2021), I will answer in a few days. I also believe your question is a matter of opinion. Some websites have static contents, others don't. And even if mixing JS and CSS and HTML is bad practice, it is done.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Not sure why you insist on emailing you. Still not getting why you posted those links... how are they related to the question in place? Still seems like you posted the links to promote them.

Comment: No, ocsigen is directly related to your question, and **your question is a matter of opinion** (so has no single "good" answer), since HTML or CSS content can be (and in 2021 often is) generated. For my websites, I am typing HTML with GNU emacs. This is not professional; I do write software which *generates* HTML

Comment: Could you please expand how ocsigen is related to my question, no getting it... and the other two links? spam? Want to drive traffic to your projects by suggesting viewers of this question to visite them?

Comment: No, I will explain by email, not here. And being in holidays, I will take several days to answer to your email. If there is a well-defined guideline, you will have found it. The fact that you did not found a guideline is meaningful. If you make a website as popular as StackOverflow, you don't have the same constraints as I do. For instance, you could generate CSS and HTML (or  mix of them) with [PHP](http://php.net/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I edited the question again. For sure there should be advantages and disadvantages which are not opinion bases of including the CSS/JS in the HTML instead of separated files, some mentioned on the initial answer already, ... not sure how the question framed in this way can still be considered opinion based... but if that's the case, then please feel free to delete the question.

Comment: An advantage could be to lower the overall bandwidth (number of total bytes exchanged to display visually the same page). A disadvantage might be the human effort involved by developers. So an internal website seen by a dozen person or less (e.g. a web server in my basement visible only to my family) has different constraints than StackOverflow (seen by millions).

Comment: Imagine you are developing some [RaspberryPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/) device monitoring the wind speed in your garden. You want to access that speed with a tablet (or mobile phone) running some web browser. For that case, you probably prefer to mix JS, CSS, HTML in the same "file" or web resource (served by [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) in the RaspBerryPi). It could be likely that you might not need a lot of JavaScript.

Comment: ... but if you are developing a web site like StackOverflow (or your favorite bank web site), your constraints are widely different. For example, banking web sites should be usable by nearly blind people. Likewise, web sites of hospitals have different constraints. And performance could be in the browser (you usually don't care about the time a mobile phone renders a web page) or in the server (read about the [C10K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) which does not matter for the wind speed in garden)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why js and css will be seperated is for bundling and minification purposes.

1. When you write them inside a HTML file, then the file size increases and takes time to load, which will degrade the performance.
2. When the js and css are separated, we can bundle them into one and then minify them. Then there is no need to fetch big files. And also, the stylesheets and js can be cached in browser which will reduce the time to fetch those files.
3. Also, if you want to develop in a single file you need to scroll multiple times to write the js and styles. Whereas for separate files, you can place them side by side and write which makes it so easy for development.

If the file is small, it doesn't matter much. It is more of a preference.

We do have some standards from w3c. You can read them [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_web_standards_model_-_HTML_CSS_and_JavaScript).

Comment: Excellent arguments.  And 4. separation of concerns (the HTML content may need localisation in several languages, or updates by the owner of the content, whereas CSS and jS may be more stable and requires different skills)

Comment: Could you explain points 1 + 2 better, because I don't think they are true. 1) I don't see how including the JS/CSS in HTML makes the files bigger. In total you will have the same file size(s). 2) Technically you could minify JS/CSS inside a HTML file, too.

Comment: @RoToRa 1. HTML actually is rendered based on user request. We can cache HTML too. But if you don't, browser has to always download the content. Whereas js, css and images used in the HTML are static. By default browser caches those static files and won't get downloaded unless there is a hard refresh. Every character occupies some memory including js and styles. As the file gets bigger, it has to download that chunk as I said above. You can switch dev tools in chrome and see the network tab. It will explain clearly what I am saying.

Comment: @RoToRa 2. Yes you could. But not all people minify html because of the dynamic content which is showed to users, based on preferences, regions, user types etc whatsoever. It is not necessary to minify it in such scenarios but css and js will still be static.